# Unkown column in field list from Embeddable Object

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I am trying to embed a `Category` into `Item`. But when I do it gives me the error that the column `category` is unkown.

```
@Embeddable
public class Category {

    private String description;

    private Category() {
        description = "undefined";
    }

    public Category(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getDiscription() {
        return description;
    }
}
```

Item

```
@Entity
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Item.getAll", query = "select a from Item as a"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Item.count", query = "select count(a) from Item as a"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Item.findByDescription", query = "select a from Item as a where a.description = :descriptions")
})
public class Item implements Comparable, Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "email")
    private User seller;

    @Embedded
    @AttributeOverrides({
        @AttributeOverride(name = "description",
                column = @Column(name = "category"))})
    private Category category;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    @OneToOne(optional = true)
    private Bid highest;

    public Item(User seller, Category category, String description) {
        this.seller = seller;
        this.category = category;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public Item() {

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The changes I made did not affect the database in anyway. So the new column was never created.